# How can I control a PowerPoint presentation on Mac using an Android device?

Tags: ms-office, keynote, android

In the past I paid and used [Remote Pro PowerPoint Keynote](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pptremotecontrol.android.presenter.fullversion), but the software that we should install on mac is not supported anymore, so it basically doesn't work.

I'm really struggling to find a solution I can use.

Any ideas?